# SVG Fragment ID + css animation. Is it supported by modern browsers?

Tags: html, css, animation, svg

Today I learned about [SVG Fragment Identifier](https://caniuse.com/?search=SVG%20Fragment) for the first time. This innovation is very useful for my site, as it will save my icons in a separate file with the .svg extension. However, some icons uses animation.
We know that there are two approaches to achieve animations present in SVG:

1. [SMIL](https://css-tricks.com/guide-svg-animations-smil/) (`<animate>`, `<animateTransform>`, etc.);
2. CSS (`animation`, `transition` and other).

When editing my site, I put all the icons in a .svg file, and in the same file I added animation using CSS rules. In modern browsers, everything worked correctly, but the rotation animation was absent in the built-in Anroid 9 Browser.
**Q**: Therefore, I was curious whether WEB standards really guarantees CSS animation when using SVG Fragment Identifier? Where is it indicated? How can I find relevant information on the [caniuse.com](https://caniuse.com)?

**For reference #1**. The animation of icons built on the basis of SMIL worked well for me on the built-in browser Anroid 9

**For reference #2**. For a better understanding, I will give an example of code in which icons are represented by a rectangle and a triangle, and the animation is done using CSS, although a similar animation can be done using `<animateTransform>`.

File: **test.svg**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <style>
  :root g { display: none;  fill: #010101; } :root g:target { display: inline; }
  
@keyframes rotate-kf {
  0% {transform: rotate(0deg);}
  100% {transform: rotate(360deg);}
}  
.rotate {
    transform-origin:center;
    animation-name: rotate-kf;
    animation-duration: 2s;
    animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    animation-timing-function: linear;
}
.rotate.reverse {
    animation-direction: reverse;
}     
  </style>
  <svg viewBox="0 0 160 160">
    <g id="icon1" class="rotate">
      <rect x="30" y="30" width="100" height="100"/>
     </g>
  </svg>
  <svg viewBox="0 0 120 120">
    <g id="icon2" class="rotate reverse">
        <polygon points="0,120 120,120 60,0" />
     </g>
  </svg>
  
</svg>
```

File: **test.htm**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head><meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"></head>
<style>
img { width: 110px;
    height: 110px;}
</style>
<body>
    <img src="test.svg#icon1"><img src="test.svg#icon2">
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Standards written down in specifications don't guarantee anything. They just help to identify the behavior of an implementing renderer as being a bug. As for documentation, there are so many variants of CSS cascades with shadow DOMs, references to external files, usage in HTML and for SVG, as presentation attributes,... that no project trying to track implementations has yet succeeded to cover everything. Bug trackers are your best bet.

Comment: @ccprog I just need to make sure that the animation work in the above code is not a side result, but a fully expected behavior.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to spec, should a SVG fragment, referenced in an HTML `<img>` element, be able to run animations? For that, the **processing mode** must be at least [secure animated](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG2/conform.html#secure-animated-mode). [Secure static mode](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG2/conform.html#secure-static-mode) would block the animation.

Suprisingly, the SVG 2 specification seems to be contradicting itself.

The [Conformance](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG2/conform.html#referencing-modes) chapter says:

> An SVG embedded within an ‘image’ element must be processed in secure animated mode if the embedding document supports declarative animation, or in secure static mode otherwise.
>
> The same processing modes are expected to be used for other cases where SVG is used in place of a raster image, such as an HTML `img` element or in any CSS property that takes an `<image>` data type. This is consistent with [HTML's requirement](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/embedded-content.html#the-img-element) that image sources must reference "a non-interactive, optionally animated, image resource that is neither paged nor scripted"

The [Linking](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG2/linking.html#processingURL-parsing) chapter has a stumbling block in the grammar used. My reading of the first word "otherwise" is that the contrasting case would be "only entire-document the URL references are valid".

> Otherwise, the subresource must be parsed to identify the target element. If the fetched document is a type that the user agent can parse to create a document object model, it must process it in secure static mode (meaning, do not fetch any additional external resources and do not run scripts or play animations or video). The document model generated for an external subresource reference must be immutable (read-only) and cannot be modified.

How is that supposed to work together? I have no idea. Maybe you should open an [issue with the Working group](https://github.com/w3c/svgwg/issues).